# How to get TikTok nowatermark video url, if I have video id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, extract, tiktoktemplate

I have a function for getting no watermarked video url from TikTok, but it don't work anymore.

**How to get TikTok nowatermark video url, if I have video id?**

```
def get_tiktok_video_nowatermark(url):
   headers = {
       "method": "GET",
       "accept-encoding": "utf-8",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
   }
   req = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

   video_data = json.loads(re.findall(u"<script id=\"__NEXT_DATA__\" type=\"application/json\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">(.*?)</script><script crossorigin=\"anonymous\" nomodule=", req)[0])

   watermark_url = video_data["props"]["pageProps"]["videoData"]["itemInfos"]["video"]["urls"][0]

   watermark_video = str(requests.get(watermark_url, headers=headers).content)

   position = int(re.search(r"vid:", watermark_video).start())

   nowatermark_url = "https://api2.musical.ly/aweme/v1/playwm/?video_id=" + watermark_video[position+4:position+36]

   return nowatermark_url
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def get_tiktok_video_nowatermark(url):
   headers = {
       "method": "GET",
       "accept-encoding": "utf-8",
       "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36"
   }
   req = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

   video_data = json.loads(re.findall(u"<script id=\"__NEXT_DATA__\" type=\"application/json\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\">(.*?)</script><script crossorigin=\"anonymous\" nomodule=", req)[0])

   watermark_url = video_data["props"]["pageProps"]["videoData"]["itemInfos"]["video"]["urls"][0]

   watermark_video = str(requests.get(watermark_url, headers=headers).content)

   position = int(re.search(r"vid:", watermark_video).start())

   nowatermark_url = "https://api.tiktokv.com/aweme/v1/play/?video_id=" + watermark_video[position+4:position+36] + "&vr_type=0&is_play_url=1&source=PackSourceEnum_PUBLISH&media_type=4&ratio=default&improve_bitrate=1"

   return nowatermark_url
```

Also, make sure you request `nonwatermark_url` without any User agent header, else you will get empty result. Better off if you can make head request to the url and determine the `final url` which can be passed directly to the browser to play or download.

Comment: Any updates/new ways for getting (Video ID) for videos that don't include "vid:" in them?

Comment: The only way right now is to use X-Gorgon & X-Khronos that is used by TikTok mobile apps to sign requests, which is quite complex for newer videos. There are few API services that can deliver non watermarked video id & urls.. you might want to look at https://rapidapi.com/wppressapi-wppressapi-default/api/tiktok-no-watermark1

Comment: Thank you Sovit!